# Radeon 7700 - 2nd DVI port disabled

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, amd-radeon

I have 2 monitors, both with VGA ports only ([LG Flatron W2242S](http://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-W2242S-lcd-monitor)).

I want to use both of these monitors with my AMD Radeon 7700 graphics card.  However, the second port refuses to work.

The cables being used are VGA > DVI male-to-male.

I think it is worth noting that these monitors come from a previous set up that enjoyed many years of happy dual-monitoring.  I'm 100% sure the fault lies with the computer, not the hardware outside of the machine.

Things I have tried:

- Both monitors work. I have tried on another machine and both work together.
- Both monitors work independently on port 1 (top port) of the graphics card.
- Neither monitor works in port 2, even with nothing else plugged in.
- I have tried new cables for both monitors, both power and VGA > DVI.
- I have swapped and changed the cables round in every possible configuration.
- Latest drivers installed and Windows fully updated.

It's probably worth noting that AMD Catalyst Control Center (AMD's driver control panel) lists the monitor as "CRT, Analog, Single".  I'm guessing VGA doesn't pass meta information to the machine, so that's just a fallback from the software, but mentioning just in case.

The card is near new, I have had it for about 3 months but only just got around to sorting out dual monitors.  It was manufacturer fitted.  The machine hasn't been stressed in any way, has more than ample power from the PSU and to be honest the thing has barely been used.

Last thing possibly worth mentioning.  I have found a few forum posts dotted about of people having the same issue, but none seem to have been resolved.  This makes me think it probably isn't a faulty card.

I'm on Windows 7.  Had the issue on a clean install of Windows, so it's not the drivers playing up.

Massive thanks in advance - I'm going a bit mad with this!

EDIT: Found a [forum](http://www.computerforum.com/228078-dual-monitors-amd-radeon-hd-7700-a.html) talking about this, apparently it needs to be an "[active adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812400402)". No outcome found on the forum - any ideas?

EDIT 2: Full Graphics Card info as found in Catalyst Control Center: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFKre.jpg

Comment: What card exactly do you have because there are dozens of GPU AMD graphic card manufactures

Comment: Here's all the info I have: http://imgur.com/pgxTEXW

Comment: The image does not provide the manufacture.  Did your purchase this card separately from the rest of the computer?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No it was purchased together and the card was manufacturer fitted

Comment: i have exactly the same problem with exactly the same card, i tried a standard dvi to vga adapter and it didn't work, so i got this from work: http://bit.ly/1rrjMUV - it looked like an active adapter but still, it's not working.. how do i recognize an active adapter? should i buy that and risk it?

Comment: right link to image: http://i.imgur.com/bW0IcBp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the second port needed an "active adapter" in order for it to work correctly.

Weirdly, upon using the active adapter, the correct meta information is picked up by my computer about the monitor (make, model, capabilities, etc).

Here is the adapter I purchased, in case anyone stumbles upon the same issue: http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-Active-Adapter-Converter-1920x1200/dp/B00C93JQXS