# VGA CLUB3D Radeon HD 7770 dvi-i port dead?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, vga, dvi, amd-radeon

I bought a new desktop computer a couple of months ago and it has a **VGA CLUB3D Radeon HD 7770 GHz Edition Core 1GHz RAM GDDR5 4.5GHz 1GB VGA DVI HDMI** graphic card mounted (product link: http://www.club-3d.com/index.php/products/reader.en/product/radeon-hd-7770-ghz-edition.1422.html). I used just one screen until now, connected to the standard VGA port and everything worked fine until I decided to add a second screen.

I plugged the second screen to the dvi-i port using a male dvi-i **single link** to female vga adapter:
[image]
the pins pattern is like this:
[image]

I connected it to the graphic card and nothing happens, nothing at all. Nothing is detected as if the port was just dead.

I investigated cables, monitor, drivers etc. everything is up to date and working so my last try was connecting my main monitor to the dvi-i port with that adapter, expecting it to work. but no.. `"no video input"` signal appears on screen.

The closest problem I found here is in this thread: [Radeon 7700 - 2nd DVI port disabled](https://superuser.com/questions/745646/radeon-7700-2nd-dvi-port-disabled) and suggests to buy an active adapter, but it's a bit expensive and I don't want to risk wasting my money.

I've used multiple monitors for years at work, and it usually was just a matter of plugging it and it would immediately work. I assembled a pretty good PC and having such a banal hardware problem is driving me mad, because I've no idea what the problem could be.

here's the available ports on the card:

[image]

Can you help in any way? Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't tell from your picture but does your DVI adapter use the four pins around the flat one (digital)? Make sure that whichever it is, matches with your monitor. If they are different then display will not work.

Comment: yes it has 4 pins, it fits the port perfectly and the screen has a vga cable. could it be a motherboard setting maybe? something like that?

Comment: So you are pretty confident that the adapter is fine? Does it work for the other port?  I haven't ever seen a setting in the BIOS for the second display but I suppose wouldn't hurt to look

Comment: Also try turning off the computer, and booting up again with only that monitor plugged into the port you are talking about. Generally the video card will switch if only one is plugged in. This can at least help you see if the port is ok.

Comment: Title doesn't match the question.  Skip the adapter use a DVI-I cable, see if that works, if it does then the port isn't dead.

Comment: @EricF yes i took the adapter i was using at work, and it is not functioning at home. i also tried rebooting the pc with only one monitor plugged in the dvi port (w/ the adapter) and nothing happens.

Comment: @Ramhound if i find a dvi cable i'll try.. you are suggesting using NO adapters at all right? i'm starting to think the video card is damaged..

Comment: It very well could be damaged whichis why I was trying to have you try many different configurations. Also calling Radeon's tech support might be beneficial since they know their cards and features well in case there is something specific that we are missing for that card.

Comment: What is the actual model of your video card?  At a glance, I don't see any dual-analog 7700 series cards out there.

Comment: @Jason sorry for that i updated my question with the exact model

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the 7700 series is **not** capable of dual analog displays.  If you look at other 7700 cards, they pretty much all have a single analog connector (usually one DVI-I).  Club 3D might have stuck the VGA port on there to appeal to people wanting a VGA output without a dongle.  AMD doesn't have a lot of documentation, so I can only speculate.

Comment: As @Ramhound suggested, hopefully at least one of your monitors has a DVI port.  Use a DVI cable and be done with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end i discovered this card doesn't support dual analog inputs, only one. to connect two monitors you'll need to use a vga **and** a digital entry (dvi to hdmi or just hdmi). using a digital to analog adapter won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to check if the port is completely dead you could measure the voltage coming out of the DVI port of your video card.  You would need a multimeter to do it though.

Pin 14 is +5v and 15 is ground.  If you put a multimeter to it and see nothing, then your port is likely dead.  A diagram of the pinout can be found myah: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface

If you can't get the ends of the multimeter in the socket you can wrap a piece of wire around the ends and try and thread that through.  If all else fails you can always connect a cable, cut the open end, strip it and measure the bare wires.  I've had trouble finding the correct colors for the data part of the cables but one thing that is consistent is that 14 is Red and 15 is Dark Brown.

Getting 5v does not necessarily mean that the port is fine hardware wise though as another socket could be keeping you from connecting, but it's something to try.

Best of luck!